# How do you convert fraction to float to decimal

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to convert a fraction to float and from that float to decimal. Here `frac3` is `7/6` and I have already converted it to float. The problem is from the float answer I want to get 50 decimals, not 15. I used `getcontext().prac=50` but things went wrong. What can I do?

```
 from fractions import*
 from decimal import*

 getcontext().prac=50
 frac1=Fraction(2,3)
 frac2=Fraction(2,4)
 frac3=frac1+frac2
 print(frac3)
 f=float(frac3)
 h=Decimal(f)
 print(h)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant:

```
getcontext().prec=50
```

and not `prac`

```
from fractions import*
from decimal import*

getcontext().prec = 50
frac1=Fraction(2,3)
frac2=Fraction(2,4)
frac3=frac1+frac2
print(frac3)
f=float(frac3)
h=Decimal(f)
print(h)
```

7/6
1.1666666666666667406815349750104360282421112060546875

Answer (score 0):

its "getcontext().prec = 50 " and not prac